# How to convert a malformed string to a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string `s` (note that the `a` and `b` are not enclosed in quotation marks, so it can't directly be evaluated as a `dict`):

```
s = '{a:1,b:2}'
```

I want convert this variable to a `dict` like this:

```
{'a':1,'b':2}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you using such a terrible serialization scheme in the first place?

Comment: Heh. Now we need BeautifulSoup for JSON.

Comment: Because my script open a file,the file content is this format.In order to facilitate,I want straight covert to dict type.

Comment: The file content is a spider from a website crawl the content,source format is this

Comment: I think what you have is YAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your string is malformed as both json and Python dict so you neither can use json.loads not ast.literal_eval to directly convert the data.

In this particular case, you would have to manually translate it to a Python dictionary by having knowledge of the input data

```
>>> foo = '{a:1,b:2}'
>>> dict(e.split(":") for e in foo.translate(None,"{}").split(","))
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

As Updated by Tim, and my short-sightedness I missed the fact that the values should be integer, here is an alternate implementation

```
>>> {k: int(v) for e in foo.translate(None,"{}").split(",") 
     for k, v in [e.split(":")]}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Note that now you have `'1'` where you should have `1`.

Answer (score 5):

This will work with your example:

```
import ast
def elem_splitter(s):
    return s.split(':',1)

s = '{a:1,b:2}'
s_no_braces = s.strip()[1:-1] #s.translate(None,'{}') is more elegant, but can fail if you can have strings with '{' or '}' enclosed.
elements = (elem_splitter(ss) for ss in s_no_braces.split(','))
d = dict((k,ast.literal_eval(v)) for k,v in elements)
```

---

Note that this will fail if you have a string formatted as:

```
'{s:"foo,bar",ss:2}'  #comma in string is a problem for this algorithm
```

or:

```
'{s,ss:1,v:2}'
```

but it will pass a string like:

```
'{s ss:1,v:2}' #{"s ss":1, "v":2}
```

---

You may also want to modify `elem_splitter` slightly, depending on your needs:

```
def elem_splitter(s):
    k,v = s.split(':',1)
    return k.strip(),v # maybe `v.strip() also?`
```

*Somebody else might cook up a better example using more of the `ast` module, but I don't know it's internals very well, so I doubt I'll have time to make that answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re,ast
regex = re.compile('([a-z])')
ast.literal_eval(regex.sub(r'"\1"', s))
```

**out:**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

*EDIT:*
If you happen to have something like `{foo1:1,bar:2}` add an additional capture group to the regex:

```
regex = re.compile('(\w+)(:)')
ast.literal_eval(regex.sub(r'"\1"\2', s))
```

Comment: What about a string of the form:  `{foo1:1}`?  You could do that with `"\w+"`, but that's no good as it will also quote `1`.

Comment: @mgilson -- you can improve the regex and capture group reference: change `re.compile('(\w+)(:)')` and `regex.sub(r'"\1"\2', s)` and you should be fine.

Comment: @root -- Yes, that will work (with appropriate raw strings in the compile) -- unless integers are allowed as dictionary keys, but no solution handles that properly yet I don't think.  I'll upvote that one :)  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with this:

```
s = "{a:1,b:2}"
content = s[s.index("{")+1:s.index("}")]
to_int = lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x
d = dict((to_int(i) for i in pair.split(":", 1)) for pair in content.split(","))
```

For simplicity I've omitted exception handling if the string doesn't contain a valid specification, and also this version doesn't strip whitespace, which you may want. If the interpretation you prefer is that the key is always a string and the value is always an `int`, then it's even easier:

```
s = "{a:1,b:2}"
content = s[s.index("{")+1:s.index("}")]
d = dict((int(pair[0]), pair[1].strip()) for pair in content.split(","))
```

As a bonus, this version also strips whitespace from the key to show how simple it is.

Answer (score -2):

```
import simplejson
s = '{a:1,b:2}'
a = simplejson.loads(s)
print a
```

Comment: -1, `simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)`

Comment: In my Python installations, I don't even get this far: `ImportError: No module named simplejson`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have it installed because I frequently run into old scripts that `import` it. For new code the right way is definitely `import json`.

Comment: 420             raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)